# World map with data display as a heat map for a web application

Tags: dictionary

Are there any toolkits / libraries which can generate a world map and overlay data in a heat map sort of view (like Google's one on http://www.google.com/insights/search/#geo=&q=wimbledon+-tennis%2Cwimbledon+tennis&cmpt=q)?

I would need to be able to generate and display the map locally, not via some webservice, and would need the output in a browser (i.e. flash or HTMP/Javascript output).

Answer (score 5):

These three solutions only work if you're online:

The [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/chart/types.html#maps) has a Chart Type of 'map'

you construct the graph by a simple GET request, so it's all in the URL. The result is a static image.

```
https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=t&chs=440x220&chd=t:0,100,50,32,60,40,43,12,14,54,98,17,70,76,18,29&chco=FFFFFF,FF0000,FFFF00,00FF00&chld=DZEGMGAOBWNGCFKECGCVSNDJTZGHMZZM&chtm=africa&chf=bg,s,EAF7FE
```

[image: example map chart of africa]

If your data is not tied to nations: the Google Maps API you can draw colored polygons
any way you like: [example](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/maps/documentation/examples/polygon-simple.html). You can achive this by using the [javascript API](http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Polylines_Overview) or by [overlaying a kml file](http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#polygon).  The endresult is a google map which you can embed in your html page.

Comment: Cheers - Can't use a web service I'm afraid (it's for an internal web app where the user may not have external internet access)

Answer (score 4):

I think Jvector Maps is the thing you are looking for.

http://jvectormap.com/

Best part is it doesnt require any Flash or any browser plug-in.

Answer (score 2):

[FusionMaps](http://www.fusioncharts.com/maps/) help you create animated, interactive and data-driven Flash Maps for your dynamic web applications. The maps are driven by XML data source and can be integrated with any scripting technology (ASP.NET, ASP, PHP, JSP, CF etc.) and database.

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers http://www.openlayers.org/ is the most featureful web-mapping client. It will happily read your data locally via standard GeoJSON files for vectors and geo-referenced images for rasters.

You could even grab a bunch of tiles from something like an OpenStreetMap tile server and serve those locally for a pretty background.

Answer (score 1):

check this address http://jquery4share.com/4-useful-interactive-map-jquery-plugins/ maybe you find what u looking for.