# FOSS mapping and data visualization framework

Tags: json, google-maps, maps, data-visualization, vector-graphics

I'm looking for something similar to, but which is NOT google maps or any other privately hosted service that might collect data (sensitive data is being shown so its a private application).

Criteria:

**1) FOSS**

**2) integrates svg maps and data sets**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've found since I posted this:

I've included a lot of information from [World map with data display as a heat map for a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286415/world-map-with-data-display-as-a-heat-map-for-a-web-application).

- http://www.openlayers.org/
- http://d3js.org/
- http://jvectormap.com/
- http://polymaps.org/